# Wordpress featured image url is using absolute host path and adding an extra / causing page to break. Why is this happening? 

Tags: wordpress

I migrated a site from my testing server to the live server. Everything transferred normally only the featured images are broken and not displaying. The URL's are being rendered incorrectly even if i re-upload the image.

the testing server is http://dave-conner.com

the live server is http://qmpdirect.com

the page where the issue is happening on is http://qmpdirect.com/cpap-kits/

the first image path should be:
 http://qmpdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sleepstyle600-37440_184x184.jpg

but is instead rendering as: 
/home/content/28/9036828/html//wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sleepstyle600-37440_184x184.jpg

If anyone can tell me why this is happening and how i can fix it I would greatly appreciate it. I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now.

Comment: You might want to try this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try this http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 2):

Login to your phpmyadmin, get in to your database, in page 3 find upload_path

Comment: just saw this. I up-voted your answer tho because it was pretty much the right solution. It was actually the temp upload folder but you are the only one that offered a viable solution on any forum. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The location of the temporary files in the database was still set to the absolute hosting path of the old server. Once i changed this to the absolute hosting path of the live server the problem was corrected. I'm still not sure why this caused the image to break since wordpress moves these images to permanent folders but...problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, solved by David Conner solution.
Details of how I solved:

- with phpmyadmin, go to `wp_options` table
- on page 4 (with default pagination of 30rows/page) you will find an option named et_images_temp_folder`with the`option_id = 154`
- replace option_value with your new absolute server path
- example of executed query:

  ```
  UPDATE  `yourdatabase`.`wp_options` 
  SET `option_value` = '/home/yourwebsite/public_html/wp-content/uploads/et_temp'
  WHERE `wp_options`.`option_id` = 154;
  ```